# Create child class in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have the following code :

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        def tt(self, dic):
            for value, item in dic:
                setattr(self, item, value)

        lar = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
        lbr = {'c': 4, 'd': 8}
        lcr = {'e': 5, 'f': 0}
        dic = {'ar': lar, 'br': lbr, 'lcr': lcr}

        for value, item in dic:
            setattr(self, item, tt(self.item, value))


rrr = test()
print(rrr.ar.gg)
```

I wanted to know if I could do that, I need to use a function 'tt' for another project, but it's to heavy to put it here, the idea stay the same.

I need to generat child class from a function in a for loop

Comment: What's the point of the nested function?

Comment: I have a lot of data and want to organise it that way

Comment: What is the `type` or `class` of your `x` attribute ?

Comment: "it's to heavy to put it here" — can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: This looks like an XY question. Are you looking to make a test object, that contains 3 more test objects (contained in the fields `ar,br,cr`), each with `gg==3`?

Comment: actually I want to make multiple objects wich names are contained in a list, and from them creat other objects contained in another list, specific to this object

Comment: OK, where is the definition for the other objects? Are they a different class?

Comment: yes they are different class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, **data):
        for k, v in data.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        kwmap = {
            'ar': {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, 
            'br': {'c': 4, 'd': 8}, 
            'cr': {'e': 5, 'f': 0}
            }

        for attrname, kw in kwmap.items():
            setattr(self, attrname, Data(**kw))


rrr = Test()
print(rrr.ar.b)  # should output 3
```

NB : I extracted the `Data` class from `Test.__init__` because it didn't depend on any local var in `Test.__init__` but you can of course declare anywhere you see fit - just remember that having the class definition in a function means a new class object is created each time the function is called, which is a waste of resources and will break any test based on the class identity.

NB2: if you need your objects to be of different classes then just put the class in the mapping - python classes are objects on their own (just like functions, modules etc):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d


class C(object):
    def __init__(self, e, f):
        self.e = e
        self.f = f


class Test2(object):
    def __init__(self, specs):
        for attrname, (cls, kw) in specs.items():
            setattr(self, attrname, cls(**kw))


test2 = Test2({
        'ar': (A, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}), 
        'br': (B, {'c': 4, 'd': 8}), 
        'cr': (C, {'e': 5, 'f': 0})
        })

print(test2.ar.b)  # should output 3
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the question I wansn't clear enougth the first time